# Whats the Most efficient way to Check if a Date is between Recurrence of a Span?

Tags: c#, algorithm, date

What's the most efficient way to check if a date falls between a repetition of a span of time using the c# date class.

E.g., you have the span 01/01/2009 1:00:00 am to 01/06/2009 5:00pm which repeats every *x* number of years, months, or weeks, etc.

And I want to check if variable date `x` falls between any recurrence

I read [Martin Fowler's paper on temporal expressions](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf) but all his examples are of single day events not ones that can span multiple days.

Comment: Is the period of repitition always going to be numerically identical (e.g. 7 days, 30 days, 365 days) or does it have to follow date driven rules, e.g. every month, every year?  If the latter, what happens in February if the period is 29th Jan to 31st Jan?

Comment: Adam I account for that by giving the user the option to select the occurrence of week of day(mon,tue, etc..) in the month, or the day of the month (which will not occur in some cases)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following condition must be true:

`(time - begin) mod period < (end - begin)`,

provided that `period > (begin - end)`

All variables should be expressed in same units (like, seconds or whatever precision you need)

Comment: Unfortunately most periods involving datetimes are not constant (months are 28-31 days long, years are 365/366 days, etc...)

Comment: This is a very neat method which will work fine for numerically constant distances between the intervals (e.g. 7 days, 30 days, 365 days) but if date driven rules are to be followed, e.g 'every month', 'every year' then something else is required (see my comment on the question).